# read and compare data through a while loop in php

Tags: php

I work with `oracle` database and `php`.I want to select all values of a field from one table.and then compare them in a while loop to find the biggest one(they are numbers).what should I do?I will show my code:

```
$dql="SELECT T21_5 FROM T21";
$dqlresult=oci_parse($conn,$dql);
oci_execute($dqlresult);
$rew=oci_fetch_assoc($dqlresult);
$max=0;
while($rew){
  if($max>$rew['T21_5']){
     $max=$max;
  }else{
     $max=$rew['T21_5'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only store the max value.

```
$max=0;
while($row){
  if($max < $row['T21_5'])
  {
     $max=$row['T21_5'];
  }
}
echo $max;//This will output the max value
```

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\investone\invoice.php on line 85